# Display attached image in email body

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a script that sends e-mails using phpmailer() with an attached image that it's also displayed in the e-mail body. The receivers that use Outlook or some mobile clients have reported that they have issues viewing the image in the e-mail body.
I've tried to check the way thunderbird attaches the signature. From what I understood the image is linked by it's attachment id but doesn't appear as attachment(I'm not looking for this exact behavior, it can still be as attachment but really need it to be displayed in outlook and mobile clients). 

So my question is how should I change my script so that my image is attached to the email the same way thunderbird attaches the signature, or is there a standard, or best practice in doing this?

Edit: code used in sending email script:

```
$subject = 'Subject - ';
$emails = get_emails()
foreach ($emails as $email) {
define("PHPMAILER",0);
$message = $content;
$path = 'xxx';
require_once ($path);
$mailer = new PHPMailer();
$mailer->SMTPDebug = true;
$mailer->IsSMTP();
$mailer->Host = 'xxx';
$mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mailer->Username = 'xxx';
$mailer->Password = 'xxx';
$mailer->FromName = 'xxx';
$mailer->From = 'xxx';
$mailer->AddAddress($email,"xxx");
$mailer->Subject = $subject;
$mailer->IsHTML(true);
//get the images that needs to be embedded
$embeds = get_images($firma_id,0);
if ($embeds == 0) {echo "No embeds";} else {
  foreach ($embeds as $key => $value) {
    $mailer->AddEmbeddedImage($value,"img".$key,"grafic_".$key.".png");
  }
  $mailer->MsgHTML($message);
  if (!$mailer->Send()) {
    exit;
  }
}
}
```

and the content looks like this:

```
             <td style='font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;'>
           <img style='margin-right: 10px;' src='cid:img".$grafic."' alt='grafic".$grafic."' width='800' align='left'>
         </td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make a name/identifier for that image attached and call that in image tag at the place(body) you want to show. Code will be like below,

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('img/image1.jpg', 'logo');

<img src='cid:logo\' />
```